# How can I develop a touchscreen GUI in Python?

Tags: python, touchscreen

I am new to touch screen programming, and I'm programming a camera in python. How can I create a touchscreen-compatible GUI in Python?

Answer (score 5):

You can try Kivy, this gives you a python multi-touch interface but has a lot of other stuff as well...

https://kivy.org/