# Touchscreen programing

Tags: touchscreen

I have to do a project for school, the project involves raspberry Pi and its touchscreen. I'm new to Pi but I'm not new to programming by any means. My question is if i want to use the touchscreen to display some GUI elements what is the way to go? is it normal Pi programming and programs are touchable if they're displayed om the touchscreen? I mean if I'm creating a GUI, can I just create a normal raspbian program and once it is displayed on the touchscreen the buttons and other elements can be access with a finger touch? Or I have to use specific libraries to make the program touchable?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you probably want to look for a UI toolkit that will work on Linux and supports touchscreen; the fact that it's a Pi isn't critical here. It'd be helpful to say which language you're using; for example [this Q&A explains how you could do it with Python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/how-do-i-program-touch-screen-in-pyton).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think Kivy will be a good match for what i'm trying to do here, which is creating GUI elements or displaying data read by Pi into the touchscreen visually?

Comment: Looks like Kivy is particularly designed for touch interfaces, so while I can't speak from personal experience, it appears suitable. If you're comfortable with Python, it should be relatively straightforward. I'll vote to close this as a duplicate of the other question; if it turns out not to be suitable, you can edit your post with your updated requirements, otherwise you can mark this as resolved for any future readers who find your question.

Comment: The RPI touchscreen uses finger presses to 'simulate' mouse movement/clicks.  So there is no difference from the the GUI standpoint. But when creating buttons and other features, they will need to be large enough to use with a finger press as it is not as precise as a mouse movement.    appJar is a very simple gui builder for python.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might not need anything as fancy as Kivy because touch events are interpreted as mouse clicks. So you could use a web tech, tkinter, pygame... Or even something as simple as Libre Impress with hyperlinks on shapes/text it's probably the quickest way to create a one-off touch app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I develop a touchscreen GUI in Python?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/how-can-i-develop-a-touchscreen-gui-in-python)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "touchable" programs. How's that different from "clickable" programs?